# I am admin on win 7, why still need to "run as admin"

Tags: windows-7, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I need to run commands as administrator if my account is member of administrator group?](https://superuser.com/questions/107358/why-do-i-need-to-run-commands-as-administrator-if-my-account-is-member-of-admini)
>   [Windows 7 “Run as Administrator” when already an Administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/379197/windows-7-run-as-administrator-when-already-an-administrator)

I was researching on internet but didn't find anything except "User Access Control".
Here is the senario, 
I have all administrator rights on my login name. when I go and see policies it says I am administrator. 
but when I am registering dll with regsvr32. it give me error to be as admin.
when I run the batch file as admin , it run successfully and register the component.
I am confused when I have all rights as administrator. Why again I need to run it "as Admin"

Comment: This is SUCH a duplicate. . . BTW, I have advise for those who don't like UAC.  Turn it off but beware the consequences. . .

Answer (score 18):

That's what UAC does.

It strips admin privileges from normally-launched processes.
This encourages you to not use dangerous admin powers where you don't need to.

Comment: Next up: how to remove the safety from your gun and why condoms are a waste of time when you could be doing the fun stuff.

Answer (score 3):

It is a basic, and very important, concept in computer security that a superuser or administrator not run routine tasks with permissions those tasks do not need. Windows implements this basic principle in a slightly different way from UNIX.

On UNIX machines, administrative users have access to two or more accounts. One of those accounts has superuser privileges, typically the `root` account, and the others don't. You usually only have one true administrative account, shared by all administrators.

Windows does this differently. Administrators usually have only a single account that holds all their privileges. But tasks don't run with with administrative privileges unless the administrator specifically asks them to.

You can think of "run as administrator" as the UNIX equivalent of "run as root" -- it means to give the task the privileges that I have the right to give it, but that wouldn't want ordinary operations having.

Conceptually, the Windows implementation is more logical. But in the actual, practical application, it doesn't seem to work quite as well as the simpler UNIX approach.

Comment: Could you give any specific examples of run as admin issues?  I'm aware there are a few cases in Win7 (more in Vista) where automatic elevation triggers more than one prompt for a single action (can't think of any in specific atm); but I thought those were because automatic elevation only requests the specific privileges Windows thinks your action will need (vs blanket admin rights) and occasionally fails to spot something not needed until 10 or 20 (internal) steps later.

Answer (score 2):

Read through this thread:  http://forums.atomicmpc.com.au/lofiversion/index.php?t45049.html

As SLaks said, this is the purpose of UAC.

Comment: "Read this link" isn't a good answer. What about 6 months from now when the link don't work? how about copy/pasting the important parts?