# Always Run as Administrator

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator

In Windows 7 you must be an `Administrator` to install or do certain functions in Windows 7. Majority of the time it ask you if you want to run as administrator to do what needs to be done. However there have been a few cases where I could not do something because I was not the administrator. How do I always run Windows 7 as an administrator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I need to run commands as administrator if my account is member of administrator group?](http://superuser.com/questions/107358/why-do-i-need-to-run-commands-as-administrator-if-my-account-is-member-of-admini)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable UAC (though not recommended for long term use):

Go to User Account Control Settings.

Type in UAC, or go to the System and Security applet.

Click on the "Change User Account Control Settings" link.

Move slider to NEVER NOTIFY.

http://www.petri.co.il/disable-uac-in-windows-7.htm

Comment: Though this is not recommended. This means you will never see a message when an app starts to run. So it might be easy to catch some nasty viruses without UAC.

Comment: @SimonVerbeke - I was afraid of that. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: Thanks for the information and your comment to open notepad as an administrator that solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonVerbeke I could've sworn I said "not recommended", but I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can normally right click the program and select "run as administrator"

Comment: The issue I am running into is I need to change a `.ini` file and it is not letting me save the file out of notepad. Tells me I must be an administrator to do this.

Comment: You should start notepad as administrator.