# How can I open notepad as Admin only using Win + R window?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

If I open **Win + R** window and type **notepad**, then notepad opens.

How can I open it as admin the same way?

Answer (score 26):

**Run Once as Admin**

The command syntax you want to use is:

```
runas /user:<localmachinename>\administrator notepad
```

NOTE:  Designating the machine name is optional.  It works like this too:

```
runas /user:administrator notepad
```

Substitute `administrator` for the account name that has admin access.  You will need to authenticate  using this process.

As @EBGreen suggested in the comments, you can save the credential on the first execution and avoid reentering it on subsequent calls.  This option only lasts for the existing logon session:

```
runas /user:administrator /savecred notepad
```

Reference:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx

**Always Run As Admin**

You can also set it so that all programs run in admin mode.  This is typically not recommended as UAC exists for a reason, but if you're so inclined follow the steps here:

[Always Run as Administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/431112/always-run-as-administrator)

Comment: You can add the /savecred flag to not be prompted in the future too.

Comment: @EBGreen how long does that last?  How could you cancel it if you needed to during the existing session?  I'm curious as that's not a setting I use often.

Comment: Actually disregard if you are on W7 (and presumably W8) since it isn't available in those environments. I believe that it lasts during the current session and as far as I know there is no way to tell it to ignore the credentials once you have given them.

Comment: @EBGreen I tested it out on W7 and WS08R2 and it worked.

Comment: Cool. I love docs that lie...

Comment: @deed02392 see *Substitute administrator for the account name that has admin access.* in the answer.

Comment: @Colyn1337, **Does not work**. I tried `runas /user:myname cmd` and entered the password in the prompt. However, the command prompt is **still** not elevated! This can be verified by typing `sfc`.

Answer (score 24):

As far as I know, this task will be started with Admin rights if it is started using <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> when UAC is disabled

[image]

Anyway, you can do the same if you press <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> key, type `notepad` in the Search field and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I think it's running all tasks as an Administrator automatically because you've got UAC turned down/off...  But +1 for suggesting using the search box & ctrl+shift+enter. :)

Comment: @techie007 If that's what it takes, post as an answer

Comment: @techie007 is right.  You only get that option if you've done this:  http://superuser.com/questions/431112/always-run-as-administrator

Comment: @CanadianLuke I considered it, but the OP doesn't say they want it to _always_ run it as admin. :)

Comment: @NikolaD If I do the same, then it doesn't run with admin privileges.

Comment: @Realo33 Win+R or ctrl+shift+enter version doesn't work for you? Win+R explained techie007... I'm always forgetting that the fact that I'm running my Wins with UAC down, doesn't mean that other people do that :). The second proposal will run notepad as admin

Comment: @NikolaD Thanks the second one works. +1 for that, but it was not the question.

Comment: @Realo33 Just edited my answer to make things more clear.

Comment: @Kevin Panko Lets make post looks even more better :):)

Comment: @NikolaD Unfortunately the domain imgur.com is blocked for me, so I do not see any of the images.  That's not your fault though.  I'm sure it looks great.

Comment: I use the start menu search box method very often that I've already abandoned the run dialog. I disabled file search for that box to make it fast and now its only purpose is to run programs in start menu and %PATH%. If you can do it so conveniently with the start menu, why would you still need the run dialog? @Realo33

Comment: Using the start menu search box, it's only a few keystrokes: `WinKey`, `cmd`, `Enter`, `Alt`+`Y`

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind using a third party program, there are several programs named `elevate.exe` written by different people. These programs work (mostly) like this:

```
elevate.exe notepad.exe
```

and then a UAC dialog pops up. Confirm it and your notepad has admin privilege.

Here's a blog post about this: http://www.raymond.cc/blog/trigger-uac-elevation-from-command-line-with-elevate-utility/

Answer (score 7):

The `runas` method often suggested has a major problem - it requires the use of a different account (`Administrator`), with the associated different profile. `Administrator` also happens to default to disabled. Running as any other standard administrative account actually uses the UAC-restricted token, defeating the purpose.

It *is* possible to elevate as your current user purely through the command line without third-party tools, though it's a little more complicated. One way is through the PowerShell `Start-Process` commandlet. The full invocation is:

```
Start-Process -Verb "runas" notepad.exe
```

Shortening it, we can get:

```
start -verb runas notepad.exe
```

Running it from the command line, or from the Run dialog:

```
powershell -c start -verb runas notepad.exe
```

It's also possible to save a script that can be run simply as `elevate`, like in [AgreeOrNot's answer](https://superuser.com/a/656872/117590) - which, again, doesn't require any third-party tools.

Answer (score 5):

I have another solution for you.

Press windows key, write down notepad and press `ctrl+shift+enter`

This will automatically open notepad (or any other programs windows searched for) as admin.

gl,

Refael

Comment: This only works when you type into the box after pressing the windows button. It doesn't work if you press Windows+R then do it (a bug IMO)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't quite answer your exact question but you can open notepad as admin by doing the following:

- Press `Windows` Key
- Type notepad
- Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

Answer (score 1):

There is a work around solution for this in [Microsoft](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/05cce5f6-3c3a-4bb8-8b72-8c1ce4b5eff1/how-to-run-a-program-as-adminitrator-via-the-command-line?forum=w7itproappcompat) forum. copy paste below lines to a notepad and save it as sudo.cmd and place it in the system32 folder

> @echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") > %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
>
> @echo args = Right("%*", (Len("%*") - Len("%1"))) >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
>
> @echo objShell.ShellExecute "%1", args, "", "runas" >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
>
> @cscript %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs

Now, take a Run terminal and type `sudo notepad`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

my case host file is read-only

and need to remove the checkmark on read-only on properties of my file.

- right click on your file
- properties
- of read-only checkbox marked remove and save and apply then you can save or overwrite it

best regards

Answer (score -1):

The Simplest Way I know to do this is to Right Click on the Normal Desktop Shortcut for the program, Choose Properties, Choose compatibility, Click off the "Run This Program as Administrator" then (if you choose) click "Change Settings for All users"  This takes care of it and stays that way.